# Big grey blocks at the bottom of each page when converting HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert (a local copy of) [this page](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/TOC.html) using wkhtmltopdf. However, every time I perform the conversion, the resulting PDF has a big gray block at the bottom of each page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do a sequence of tests.

1. Remove some elements from the sample page
2. Generate the PDF
3. Check if the big gray block is still there
4. If yes, continue with 1.
5. If no you have found the element which causes the gray block to appear.

HTH